# How to Loop Object keys and display in table using angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have data:

```
   data = {
    "laptop": [
        "dell", 
        "hp", 
        "lenovo", 
        "acer", 
        "asus"
    ],
    "mobile": [
        "lenovo", 
        "motorolla", 
        "apple", 
        "samsung"
    ] 
}
```

I am trying to display it in the table using the `ngFor` for displaying the data in the below format

[image]

But I am unable to get the data in the below rather than I am getting only data in the traditional format leaving laptop,mobile keys
is there any way to do that in the template

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfuwel)

is there any alternative approach or better becoz in future i may get n rows for the table

Comment: your stackblitz does not have any code

Comment: I can't see anything in your stackblitz. Also, it's not that easy to understand your question.  What is "the traditional format"?

Comment: To get Object keys you can use `Object.keys(data)`. The rest of this is straight forward.

Comment: @Chellappan actually i pasted it but it is not displaying it i dont know why

Comment: @Nick actually i pasted it but it is not displaying it i dont know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
get dataKeys() { return Object.keys(this.data); }
```

This will create an array of the keys of your object.

You can now use a loop on it :

```
<div *ngFor="let key of dataKeys">
  <div *ngFor="let item of data[key]">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using angular 6.1 you can use keyvalue

```
<div *ngFor="let title of data | keyvalue">
  {{title.key}}
</div>
```

Example :https://stackblitz.com/edit/keyvalue-pipe